# Modal not triggering for email from validation but email sending - bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a modal, using bootstrap for the error or success msg but its not being triggered? The email will send if all the fields are filled out (no success msg) and wont send if one or more fields are left blank (no success msg)? You can see the form [here](http://www.couchguard.com.au/boot/contact/contact.php):

This site is a work in progress and I'm new to all this bootstrap!

What am I missing?

Here's the html & triggering script:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">
           <div id="formMode" class="modal fade">
              <div class="modal-header"></div>
              <div class="modal-body"></div>
              <div class="modal-footer"></div>
           </div>
           <form action="contact.php" method="POST" id="contactform" class="form-horizontal">
              <fieldset>
                 <legend>Please fill in the form bellow and a sales representive will be in contact swiftly.</legend>
              //form details
             </div>
           </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var mode_value = getQuerystring('mode');

                switch (mode_value) {
                case '':
                $('#formMode').modal('hide');
                break
                case 'POST':
                $('.modal-header').html('h1>Form submitted...</h1>');
                $('.modal-body').html('<h2>Everything <em>seemed</em> to be correct.</h2>');
                $('.modal-footer').html('<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>');
                $('#formMode').modal('show');
                break
                case 'success':
                $('.modal-header').html('');
                $('.modal-body').html('<div class="alert alert-block alert-success"><h4 class="alert-heading">Your message was sent</h4>We will respond to you shortly</div>');
                $('.modal-footer').html('<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>');
                $('#formMode').modal('show');
                break
                case 'fail':
                $('.modal-header').html('');
                $('.modal-body').html('<div class="alert alert-block alert-error"><h4 class="alert-heading">The message was not sent</div>');
                $('.modal-footer').html('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>');
        $('#formMode').modal('show');

                };
        })
     </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you loading the JQuery UI, as the `.modal()` method does not come with the standard JQuery lib

Comment: @SamuelCook I got the idea from here [link](https://github.com/damarusama/bootstrap_contact_form.git) the html format is very similar but the script is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the script lines from the contact form after the **Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster** scripts. After that it works for me.